# getting data using Importxml into a spread sheet

Tags: excel, web-scraping, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I tried to import xml data from a website to a spreadsheet, but most of the xpaths work except this one, it keeps throwing errors

This is my full syntax:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://egypt.souq.com/eg-en/2724304505488/s/","//*[@id="content-body"]/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/h1")
```

Is this a problem with Google spread sheet or what ?

Comment: You're going to have to provide more code and details of the error you're getting

Answer (score 0):

You've used double quotes inside your XPath query. Switching these for single quotes allows sheets to parse the formula correctly:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://egypt.souq.com/eg-en/2724304505488/s/","//*[@id='content-body']/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/h1")
```

But this still results in an error:

```
Error
Imported XML content cannot be parsed.
```

You haven't been very specific but you can get the H1 content from the page in your code with this:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://egypt.souq.com/eg-en/2724304505488/s/","//h1")
```

This may well break for other pages, though.